# Libreoffice calc saving all column data into one

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I created a csv file with two columns in it.When I tried to open it in word,all data combined into one column.
I saved file as utf-16 and field delimeter as none,string delimeter as none.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you set field delimiter as none, then you've eliminated the commas that *define* CSV: "**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues". Without a delimiter between fields, they're just quoted text. Look at your *ersatz* CSV file in Notepad to see that.
2. Why save as CSV? Use a format that MS *Word* can integrate directly into a document, such as XLS? Drag and drop that format of file into *Word*.

[image: Calc File Formats]

Comment: Thanks for your response.I saved the file with field delimeter as comma but still it combined all data into one column with separate with comma.

Comment: Word does not parse CSVs, Why don't you copy paste the table from Excel to Word?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Perhaps there was only a Word licence. Just guessing.